# How to make Enter Key a submit key in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a visual basic programming on Visual Studio 2012. AnyWay I was Programming login screen(not using SQL) And I wrote down the password and pressed Enter But It doesn't Tab Works, How do I make Enter Key like a Submit key?(I tried &~ Shortkeys)

Answer (score 1):

Is this WinForms or Web?

If it's WinForm development, set the `Form.AcceptButton` at design time.
You can also set the `Form.CancelButton` to handle the `Esc` key if you wish.

Comment: Thank you Very Much! Also It was a Winform Development.

Comment: If this solved the problem, you can tick it as being correct.